# what kind of pump and attachment to tie my improvised shower to the sink drain?

Tags: plumbing, shower

I have set up a low-budget shower in an office bathroom. The below pic shows the rig before hanging the shower curtain.

Right now, I have to pick up the big bucket and dump it into the toilet.

I would like to rig up a small self priming pump, to pump out at least most of the water, preferably tied right into the sink ring trap.

Suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a "wye tailpiece" from a plumbing shop. These are normally sized for kitchen sink drains (1 1/2" tube) so you may have to adapt it (it can be done with creative use of drain fittings).

[image]

Use a submersible fountain pump, they are small and self-priming (please ensure that it is plugged into a GFCI). Just run a hose from the pump discharge to the tailpiece (again, may need creative adapting).

[image]